# Liveness/Readiness Probes Failing when using Talisman for Flask/Python

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, https, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using a Flask app deployed into Google Kubernetes Engine. The deployed application uses [Waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/stable/runner.html#) to serve the Flask application. I would like to ensure that all connections are over https. My deployed application currently allows http and/or https, but I would like to force https. To do so, I am trying to use [Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman).

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_talisman import Talisman

app = Flask(__name__)
Talisman(app)
```

However, when I deploy the version using Talisman, my probes fail and I cannot access the web app.

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    port: 8080
    path: /health
  initialDelaySeconds: 60
  timeoutSeconds: 1
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    port: 8080
    path: /health
  initialDelaySeconds: 60
  timeoutSeconds: 1
```

I tried adding `scheme: HTTPS` to `httpGet`, but the probes still fail.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you need to set up tls termination at the ingress level and then have unencrypted traffic flow from the ingress towards your service. Either that or setup MTLS within your cluster

Comment: how are you testing the access? first step would be logging inside the pod with `kubectl exec` and test the app with curl, this way we can determine if the issue is on the app or in kubernetes